# don't know how to solve the problem with the argument combination for ctc_loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Im trying to make a voice2text program and have problem with error calculation. For this I use LJSpeech dataset. This is the code:

```
import os
import csv
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
from torch import nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchaudio
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

DATASET = "data"
CHARSET = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,."
XMAX = 810
YMAX = 150
SAMPLE_RATE = 22050

def get_metadata():
    ret = []
    with open(os.path.join(DATASET, 'metadata.csv'), newline = '') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:
            answer = [CHARSET.index(c)+1 for c in row[1].lower() if c in CHARSET]
            if len(answer) <= YMAX:
                ret.append((os.path.join(DATASET, 'wavs', row[0]+".wav"), answer))
    print("got metadata", len(ret))
    return ret

mel_transform = torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(SAMPLE_RATE, n_fft=1024, win_length=1024,
                                                              hop_length=1024, n_mels=80)
def load_example(x):
    waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(x, normalize=True)
    if sample_rate != SAMPLE_RATE:
        print(f"Sample rate mismatch in file {x}. Expected {SAMPLE_RATE}, but got {sample_rate}.")
    assert(sample_rate == SAMPLE_RATE)
    mel_specgram = mel_transform(waveform)
    return mel_specgram[0].T

cache = {}
class LJSpeech(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.meta = get_metadata()
        #self.sample_rate = 22050

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.meta)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if idx not in cache:
            x, y = self.meta[idx]
            cache[idx] = load_example(x), y
        return cache[idx]
    
class GoodBatchNorm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(channels)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        #return self.bn(x.permute(1, 2, 0)).permute(1, 2, 0)
        #return x
        xx = x.permute(1, 2, 0)
        xx = self.bn(xx)
        xx = xx.permute(2, 0, 1)
        return xx

class Rec(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # (L, N, C)
        H = 256
        self.prepare = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(80, H),
            GoodBatchNorm(H),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(H, H),
            GoodBatchNorm(H),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.encoder = nn.GRU(H, H, batch_first=False)
        self.decode = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(H, H//2),
            GoodBatchNorm(H//2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(H//2, len(CHARSET))
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.prepare(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(self.encoder(x)[0])
        x = self.decode(x)
        return torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, dim=2)
    
def pad_sequence(batch):
    sorted_batch = sorted(batch, key = lambda x: x[0].shape[0], reverse=True)
    input_lengths = [x[0].shape[0] for x in sorted_batch]
    target_lengths = [len(x[1]) for x in sorted_batch]
    sequences = [x[0] for x in sorted_batch]
    sequences_padded = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(sequences, batch_first=True)
    # YMAX = max(input_length)
    #labels = [x[1] + [0]*(YMAX - len(x[1])) for x in sorted_batch]
    #labels = torch.LongTensor(labels)   
    #labels = labels[:, :max(target_lengths)]
    labels = sum([x[1] for x in sorted_batch], [])
    labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.int32)
    return sequences_padded, labels, input_lengths, target_lengths

def get_dataloader(batch_size):
    dset = LJSpeech()
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, 
                                                collate_fn=pad_sequence, drop_last=True)
    return dset, trainloader

import wandb

WAN = False

def train():
    batch_size = 64
    if WAN:
        wandb.init(project="...", entity="...") 
    config={
        "learning_rate": 0.001,
        "epochs": 100,
        "batch_size": batch_size,
    }
    dset, trainloader = get_dataloader(batch_size)
    #ctc_loss = nn.CTCLoss(reduction='mean', zero_infinity='True').cuda()
    #model = Rec().cuda()
    ctc_loss = nn.CTCLoss(reduction='mean', zero_infinity='True')
    model = Rec()
    #optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    val = torch.tensor(load_example('data/wavs/LJ037-0171.wav'))
    for epoch in range(100):
        if WAN:
            wandb.watch(model)
        mguess = model(val[:, None])
        pp = ''.join([CHARSET[c-1] for c in mguess[:, 0, :].argmax(dim=1) if c != 0])
        print('Validation: ',  pp)
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'./models/speech_{epoch}.pt')

        t = tqdm(trainloader, total=len(dset)//batch_size)
        ind = 0
        for data in t:
            input, target, input_length, target_length = data
            #input_length = torch.as_tensor(input_length)
            #target_length = torch.as_tensor(target_length)

            #input = input.cuda()
            #input = input.to('cuda:0', non_blocking=True)
            #target = target.cuda()
            #target = target.to('cuda:0', non_blocking=True)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            guess = model(input)

            pp = ''.join([CHARSET[c-1] for c in guess[:, 0, :].argmax(dim=1) if c != 0])
            if len(pp) > 0:
                print(pp)
            #print(input_length.type())
            #print(f'guess : {guess} ; target : {target} ; input size {input_length} ; target size : {target_length}')
            loss = ctc_loss(guess, target, input_length, target_length)
            ind = ind + 1
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            t.set_description("loss: %.2f" % loss.item())
            if WAN:
                wandb.log({"loss": loss})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rec.py", line 170, in <module>
    train()
 File "rec.py", line 161, in train
    loss = ctc_loss(guess, target, input_length, target_length)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1756, in forward
    return F.ctc_loss(log_probs, targets, input_lengths, target_lengths, self.blank, self.reduction,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "torch\nn\functional.py", line 2631, in ctc_loss
    return torch.ctc_loss(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ctc_loss() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, int, int, str), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor log_probs, Tensor targets, tuple of ints input_lengths, tuple of ints target_lengths, int blank, int reduction, bool zero_infinity)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, int, int, str)
 * (Tensor log_probs, Tensor targets, Tensor input_lengths, Tensor target_lengths, int blank, int reduction, bool zero_infinity)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, int, int, str)
```

Can someone explain what causes the error and how can i fix it? Also, I can't understand why the error also says about 2 additional int and str.

I tried to convert input_length and target_length into tensors. However, it didnt work for me.

Comment: `zero_infinity` should be boolean.

Comment: thanks, now it works. However my lose equals none